# How to show contents of $http.get when the file is not JSON?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show the contents of a file on a webpage. I am calling the file using Angular's $http directive like so:

```
$http.get('p/About.java').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // This prints the contents of the file.
    this.about = data; // This does nothing.
});
```

The contents of the file print in the console. However, they aren't appearing in the View:

```
foo{{$ctrl.about}}bar
```

The View prints this: `foobar`. Why won't it print the response even though its printing in the console?

Comment: Context of `this` inside of $http is different from your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this`(context) inside `.success` function is different than context(`this`) of controller function, because in javascript each function has its own context unless its explicitly bounded to outer scope.

```
var self = this; //at the top of your controller, then use self instead of this
....
$http.get('p/About.java').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // This prints the contents of the file.
    self.about = data; // This does nothing.
});
```

ES6 Version(using arrow function)

```
$http.get('p/About.java').success(data => {
    console.log(data); // This prints the contents of the file.
    self.about = data; // This does nothing.
});
```